# Specifying type of generic variable in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a generic component which can expect data of two types only:

```
interface X{
    name: string,
    path: string,
    type: string,
}

interface Y{
    name: string,
    path: string,
}
```

Both types X,Y have two common properties and X has one extra.
Now I am defining the type this way:

```
export class MyComponent<T extends X | Y> implements OnInit{
    @Input() data: T[];
    func(item: T){
        let temp = this.data.find(x => x.name === item.name);
        <<....some code....>>
    }
}
```

Calling this from the parent component this way:

```
<my-component [data]="xList"></my-component>     <!-- xList: X[] -->
<my-component [data]="yList"></my-component>     <!-- yList: y[] -->
```

This is working fine but I am not sure if this `<T extends X | Y>` is the correct way to do this or not. Can anybody please suggest the best approach here?
Can we write something like `where T implements X | Y` in Typescript?

Or should I just use `@Input() data: any[];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is fine but I would do `T extends Y` only because the `type` key is extra on the X and this component would break if we feed it an input of type array of Y and the component messes around with the `type` key.

Comment: No, this component doesn't do anything with type key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Angular framework would know the generic argument T when it instantiate `MyComponent`. the only thing i can think of is to get an instance of the component at runtime and try to set the generic type yourself which will make any diffrence as the `MyComponent` would be instanciated already and the `@Input() data` would be set.

I think you should just write `@Input() data: X[] | Y[]`.

Comment: `@Input() data: X[] | Y[]` would lead to error in `this.data.find(x => x.name === item.name)`